# Finding the index of element in a numpy array the closest to meshgrids

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following meshgrids `omega`, `phiy`, and `phix`.

```
import numpy as np

phi=np.linspace(-0.75,0.75,num=4)
omega=np.linspace(-100,100,num=5)
omega,phiy,phix=np.meshgrid(omega,phi,phi,sparse=True,indexing='ij')

rand=np.random.rand(5,4)
```

Then I want to get the following `C`

```
def f(j,k):
   return np.argmin(np.abs(phi[j]**2+np.sin(phi[k])-phi))


C=np.empty((5,4,4))
for i in range(5):
  for j in range(4):
    for k in range(4):
       C[i,j,k]=rand[i,f(j,k)]
```

Are there any more compact and better ways to get it, using some tools for meshgrids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite a bit faster by eliminating the `for` loops and using vectorized operations only to compute your `f` function:

```py
# f_mat[i,j] contains f(i,j)
f_mat = np.abs((phi[None].T**2 + np.sin(phi))[...,None] - phi).argmin(-1)
C = rand[:,f_mat]
```